# How to avoid to force unwrap a date .second component?

Tags: swift, macos, nsdate

I'm using this code to create a document for a document base application for macOS, which hase as name the seconds elapsed since the Date() referencing date.

```
func saveDocumentInApplicationSupport() {
    do
    {
        // create a directory in Application Support
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let appSupportURL = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("com.myCompany.myApp")
        let directoryURL = appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("com.myCompany.myApp").appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        try fileManager.createDirectory (at: directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        // set a name for the file
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) // "2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
        let seconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, to: Date()).second // eg. 517848179

        let fileName = "\(seconds!).idoc" // avoid force unwrapping here
        // eg. 517848179.idoc

        //  Create document
        let documentURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent (fileName)
        try document.write (to: documentURL, ofType: "com.myCompany.idoc")
    }
    catch
    {
        print("An error occured")
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to avoid to force unwrap the seconds variable?

Comment: Try using an if let statement to check for the seconds before setting it.

Comment: In such a case, where you're absolutely certain that `.second` is there (because **you** put it there!), you're completely justified to force unwrap. I would just move the force unwrap to the end of the expression.

Comment: That `"com.myCompany.myApp"` string should really be obtained programmatically ...

Comment: @Alexander I agree with grabbing the bundle name programmatically. However since we don't really know how the application is being used I think optional binding might be a safer route than force unwrapping?

Comment: @butter_baby What what would you do with in the `nil` case? Not crashing doesn't mean "safer". Falling back to nonsensical error-handling measures is *worse* than crashing.

Comment: You can just use `Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` to avoid using `Calendar` completely, btw.

Comment: @Alexander I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let theDate = Date()

let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) // "2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
let seconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, to: theDate).second!
```

is the same as directly calling:

```
let seconds = Int(theDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
```

Comment: Since the question is asking the best way to avoid the force-unwrap, this answer is best because it completely avoids the need to force-unwrap while using much simpler code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're chasing a red herring. Your worried about this one force unwrap, yet your whole block of code is surrounded in a `do`/`catch` which contains multiple `try`s, completely ignores the error, and does little in the way of damage control.

My only suggestion would be to move the force unwrap to the definition of `seconds`:

```
func saveDocumentInApplicationSupport() {
    do {
        // create a directory in Application Support
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let appSupportURL = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("com.myCompany.myApp")
        let directoryURL = appSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("com.myCompany.myApp").appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        try fileManager.createDirectory (at: directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        // set a name for the file
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) // "2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"
        let seconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, to: Date()).second!

        let fileName = "\(seconds).idoc" // eg. 517848179.idoc

        //  Create document
        let documentURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent (fileName)
        try document.write (to: documentURL, ofType: "com.myCompany.idoc")
    }
    catch {
        print("An error occured")
    }
}
```

Force unwrapping is *not universally "bad"*. Your use of the force unwrap operator is entirely justified because you **just** defined the `dateComponents` as having a `.second` component. In this case, even if you did use conditional binding to "safely" unwrap your optional, what would you do in the `nil` case?